# insufficient permission after Gitosis configuration

Tags: security, git, gitosis

I tried setting up gitosis following both website.  Setup went through fine, when developer clone and try to push they get

error --> insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects error

How do we handle this? Do i need to change permission of object. Currently it is 755 permission.

http://www.sparksupport.com/blog/git-access-control-with-gitosis-2/comment-page-1#comment-185 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to `chmod -R` the whole objects directory.

Also you should really be using gitolite. Gitosis is not being updated anymore. Word is slow getting out about that, but the community really has moved to gitolite.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try with Gitolite.